# C# Is there a way to put a Null-conditional operator (?) on T?

Tags: c#, generics, null-conditional-operator

I have an `interface<T>`. This interface has a method `Compare(T x, T y)`.

- `x` can never be `null`.
- `y` has a large chance of being `null`.

I want to make this clear by using the Null-conditional operator `?` on `y`: `Compare(T x, T? y)`.

Is this possible and from what version of C#?

**EDIT:**

`T` can be a reference type and a value type.

Comment: That's not a null-conditional operator. `T?` specifies a nullable type. For value types it generates a `Nullable<T>` parameter. For reference types it does nothing since they're already nullable. In C# 8 and later, assuming nullable type checking is enabled, `T` would never accept a null while `T?` would. Have you tried it? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: Is T a reference type? It it is, then you can't guarantee that "x can never be null" so that's a false statement. If it's a value type see Panagiotis comment. `T` (e.g. `int`) and `Nullable<T>` (e.g. `int?`) are different types

Comment: In C# 8 and later you *can* have the compiler ensure that `T` won't accept any nulls if you use [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).That only applies to your code and libraries that are compiled with support for NRTs though (the BCL supports them).

Comment: The article on Nullable reference types - specifically on generics - answers my question. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a document suggested by @PanagiotisKanavos:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics

In C# 8.0, using `T?` without constraining `T` to be a `struct` or a `class` did not compile. That enabled the compiler to interpret `T?` clearly. That restriction was removed in C# 9.0, by defining the following rules for an unconstrained type parameter `T`:

- If the type argument for `T` is a reference type, `T?` references the corresponding nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string`, then `T?` is a `string?`.
- If the type argument for `T` is a value type, `T?` references the same value type, `T`. For example, if `T` is an `int`, the `T?` is also an `int`.
- If the type argument for `T` is a nullable reference type, `T?` references that same nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string?`, then `T?` is also a `string?`.
- If the type argument for `T` is a nullable value type, `T?` references that same nullable value type. For example, if `T` is a `int?`, then `T?` is also a `int?`.

**For my question, this means I need to constrain `T` to a class, since I am on C#8.**

Comment: Compare is never used with nullable. Both objects have the possibility of being null which is checked inside the method and decision is taken accordingly.

Comment: Say you have a list and you want to compare each item in it with values of a different list. This is the entire purpose of the application. Then you would loop through items of list `x`. Now assume the lists cannot contain `null`. Then `x` could never be null. I want to ensure an exception when `x` is `null`, because it's not supposed to be able to. Using `T?` would fit best for my usecase.

Comment: Then you should do List<T>

Comment: Yes but say you have a list of lists of lists of lists of lists of lists etc. and you want to make the method recursive, then the deepest item will not be of type List<T> but of T.

Comment: Then you do IEnumerable<T> and do Linq's SelectMany till the time it does not become a flat list.

Answer (score 0):

Given that till this answer is written, it's not mentioned that if there is a condition on `T` like this

```
public interface IDoWork<T> : where T: ???
{...}
```

we'll assume it to be a reference type

Now that it's assumed that `T` is a reference type then you should do this

```
public int Compare(T x, T y)
{

    if (y == null)
        //Take decision accordingly.
    else
        //Take decision accordingly.
}
```

Compare methods do not take parameters as nullable types. They take pure instances and then inside the method decide according to the expected behaviour.